# Calling commands from pom.xml based on OS

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I want my pom.xml to act according to the OS.  This pom serves my purpose for linux64 and windows 64. but how do i trigger two different commands for windows 32 (both server and client)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<groupId>xyz</groupId>
<artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>xyz</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>xyz</groupId>
            <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>xyz</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <compileConfig>
                            <param>
                                <os>windows</os>
                                <environment>
                                    <property>
                                        <name>WINARCH</name>
                                        <value>${xyz.platform}</value>
                                    </property>
                                </environment>
                                <commands>
                                    <param>
                                        <command>devenv /Rebuild "Release|x64"
                                            %WORKSPACE%/main/dev/server/server.sln || exit /b</command>
                                        <directory>build</directory>
                                        <quiet>true</quiet>

                                    </param>
                                </commands>
                            </param>
                            <param>
                                <os>nix</os>
                                <environment>
                                    <property>
                                        <name>UNIXARCH</name>
                                        <value>${xyz.platform}${xyz.nix_build_config}</value>
                                    </property>
                                </environment>
                                <commands>
                                    <param>
                                        <directory>build</directory>
                                    </param>
                                    <param>
                                        <command>make clean;make_nowarn</command>
                                        <directory>build</directory>
                                    </param>

                                    <param>
                                        <command>./failIfWarning.sh</command>
                                        <directory>build</directory>
                                    </param>
                                </commands>
                            </param>
                        </compileConfig>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>

        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Have you looked at [`profiles`](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)?

Comment: Thanks  @AndrewLogvinov, profiles seems to be best suiting this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tip with profiles is the right direction like this:

```xml
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>windows</id>
      <activation>
        <os>
          <family>Windows</family>
        </os>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>..</groupId>
            <artifactId>..</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              Windows part
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>linux</id>
      <activation>
        <os>
          <family>Unix</family>
        </os>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>..</groupId>
            <artifactId>..</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              Linux part
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
```

Comment: thanks, a query.. will I have to repeat the plugins in all the profiles? can I have a common section? Also_in win32 I am getting the following error "The plugin 'xxx' does not exist or no valid version could be found" which works fine for win64 and linux64._Could you please help me with that too.